# Is PuTTY (PSFTP) using binary mode to transfer a file in from some server to Windows client?

Tags: sftp, putty, file-transfer

Is PuTTY (PSFTP) using binary mode to transfer a file in from some server to Windows client?

How do I know about file transfer mode in PuTTY PSFTP?

FYI, in command line, we are not specifying any transfer mode. Server OS, I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PSFTP uses an SFTP protocol version 3.

In the SFTP protocol version 3 there are no transfer modes. Or in other words, there's only a binary transfer mode.

---

If you need "ascii download", you need to convert the downloaded file to Windows format after you download it with PSFTP.

Or use another Windows SFTP client that can do it for you.

---

For example [WinSCP SFTP client](https://winscp.net/) supports the "ascii download".

If the server supports SFTP version 4 or newer, that supports "ascii download" natively, it uses that. If not, WinSCP converts the file after download automatically.

This is a simple batch file (`.bat`) to download a file in ascii mode in WinSCP:

```
winscp.com /log="c:\path\sftp.log" /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/" ^
    "get -transfer=ascii /remote/path/file.txt c:\local\path\file.txt" ^
    "exit"
```

For details see:

- [guide to WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) and
- [guide to converting PSFTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_psftp_script_to_winscp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: thanks martin  :) So There is no way we can download file in ASCII mode using putty... ? some other version of putty or any other way

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks martin ... thanks that will work . i will try tomorrow

Comment: yeah sure :) happy to do that